# In Tortoise SVN I'm about to commit 'replaced' files, but I want to change them to be 'modified' in order to keep revision history

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Nuget in visual studio 2013 has modified a bunch of files, but for some reason in the SVN commit list they show up as 'replaced', however I want to change them to be 'modified' before committing them.

I want to do this in order to keep revision history.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that whatever action you did, you *deleted* the files in question, then *added* them back in.

You can solve this by doing the following:

1. Move the file marked as being *replaced* out of the working directory into a temporary location.
2. Revert the file missing file. This will return the copy of the old file.
3. Now copy over the recently *reverted* file with the copy you moved out of the working directory.

My understanding is that NuGet is a dependency/package manager much like Maven and Ant are for JAR management in Java development. If that is so, what files is NuGet replacing? Are these dependencies that are being replaced?

If this is the case, delete those files, and keep those packages out of your repository. You should be able to use [Package-Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/Consume/Package-Restore) to download the need packages as part of your build process. This will prevent the entire *replace vs. modified* issue from happening in the first place.